# ASP.Net Cookie Problems

Tags: asp.net

I have a cookie when a User loges in:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Username");
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0);
                    cookie.Value = txtUsername.Text;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and it reads out in the Login-Page when the user visit again:

```
if (Response.Cookies["Username"] != null) txtUsername.Text = Response.Cookies["Username"].Value;
```

But when I log in, and after that I log out directly, the cookie is deleted. It has neither the exp-date nor the value saved.

Whot do I wrong?

Comment: How are you testing this? Have you checked using a browser embedded developer tool like Firebug for Firefox to monitor what is happening with cookies on the client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (Response.Cookies["Username"] != null) txtUsername.Text = Response.Cookies["Username"].Value
```

should be

```
if (Request.Cookies["Username"] != null) txtUsername.Text = Request.Cookies["Username"].Value
```